# Why is BugSense missing exceptions?

Tags: android, bugsense

My app has an occasional bug in it. Flurry shows me this:

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException
Msg: Unable to resume activity {com.blag.myapp/com.blah.myapp.activity.MyActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But with no line number or stack trace it's hard to know the cause. The activity makes a call to BugSenseHandler.setup() in onCreate() and it usually works, but sometimes BugSense fails to report a fatal exception.

Am I doing something wrong, or is BugSense unreliable?

Comment: paste the complete error here

Comment: I having another problem, my app that crash on android 3.0 does not sent any crash report but I tested with others phone , android 3.0 below it does sent

Comment: Try using the latest library. It was an error that has been resolved: http://blog.bugsense.com/post/11992115529/thread-reporting-for-all-android-devices-1-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is strange (BugSense co-founder here). We've never had any problems reported.
Maybe Dalvik is killing everything?

Is your app a widget?

Comment: It's an activity that is crashing - there's no app widget in this app. As you suggested on Twitter, I've disabled Flurry in case Flurry is swallowing some exception. It's not clear yet if it's succeeded. Thx.

Comment: Having upgraded to the latest BugSense release at your suggestion Jon, this now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried bugsense  it only gives you log when force close dialog occurs in application ,and when some error occurs but it is handled by try catch then bugsense does not give log

Comment: The app is force closing, but BugSense is not logging an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that your app has crashed? or keep running?

I think that Flurry shows many Error Exceptions that do not crash the app or just handled, Flurry's reports have too less information, so you cannot really understand what is going on.

Comment: The app is crashing - dead, shut down, force close, fatal exception.